Avoid relative dates in Android 13 notifications
While I'd like to avoid relative dates system wide for any application and any Android version, there is one special case where I would like this: I need to know at which exact time (like for example 14:36) a notification arrived, but it shows dates like "2h ago" and "3h ago"
Is this possible in Android 13 or Android 14?

This may be a app dependent feature: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#when

Have you checked notification history?

Yes, notification history also displays relative dates
